# If $f$ is monotone increasing and $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, then $f'(x_{0}) \geq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let $X$ be a subset of $\textbf{R}$, let $x_{0}\in X$ be a limit point of $X$, and let $f:X\rightarrow\textbf{R}$ be a function. If $f$ is monotone increasing and $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, then $f'(x_{0}) \geq 0$. If $f$ is monotone decreasing and $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, then $f'(x_{0})\leq 0$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

**Lemma**

Let $X\subseteq\textbf{R}$, $f:X\rightarrow\textbf{R}$, $g:X\rightarrow\textbf{R}$, $x_{0}\in X$ is an adherent point, $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for every $x\in X$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f(x) = L$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}g(x) = M$. Then we have that $L \leq M$.

**Proof**

According to the definition of limit, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there are $\delta_{1} > 0$ and $\delta_{2} > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
0 < |x - x_{0}| < \delta_{1}\\\\
0 < |x - x_{0}| < \delta_{2}
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon\\\\
|g(x) - M| < \varepsilon
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow L - \varepsilon < f(x) \leq g(x) < M + \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Let us assume that $L > M$. In this case, we can choose $\displaystyle\varepsilon = \frac{L - M}{3}$, whence we get that
\begin{align*}
M - L + 2\varepsilon > M - L + \frac{2(L - M)}{3} = \frac{M - L}{3} > 0 \Longrightarrow M > L
\end{align*}
which leads to a contradiction. Therefore the original claim is true and $L \leq M$.

**Solution**

Assuming that $f$ is monotone increasing at $x_{0}$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x) - f(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}} \geq 0
\end{align*}

Taking the limit from both sides to $x_{0}$ we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x) - f(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}} = f'(x_{0}) \geq 0 = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}0
\end{align*}

simliar reasoning applies to the monotone decreasing case, and we are done.

Could someone please verify if I am arguing correctly? Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: I don’t think you need the lemma. Just observe that the numerator and denominator in the limit expression for the derivative are both always positive

Comment: Why do you even wrote a lemme? It looks like your solution is self-contained and correct.

Comment: Does the Lemma say that $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in X$ ?

Comment: @Pritam Yes, it does. I forgot to mention. I just edited it.

Comment: @BrickByBrick yup your proof is right but as Jonathan said you don't need the lemma at all...the proof is pretty obvious as the function is said to be monotone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you even write the lemme? It looks like your solution is self-contained and correct.
Perhabs this helps you : $$(D_{x_0}f)(x):=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ is continuous everywhere, by the definition of the $f$. Then by your argument, ($D_{x_0}f\geq 0$ everywhere) $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}(D_{x_0}f)(x)\geq 0.$$